# Term for being responsible for previous customers after taking over a company

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

Slightly abstract question but i'm after a single word that describes this:

Say your company buys another company that provides a service - is there a word that describes that you are still responsible for your previous customers paying for your service and indeed the customers that were previously paying for the services of the company you have now taken over?

e.g. a word describing the transfer of liabilities after acquisition

Comment: I don't know [if this](https://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/goodwill)  works in your case, but..."_Goodwill_ ... can be considered as the amount by which the value of the business as a whole exceeds the assets minus the value of the company's liabilities."

Answer (score 1):

"**Inherited liabilities**" (of acquisition or merger) is what I might call them.

> NEW HAVEN, Conn., March 13, 2018 (GLOBE NEWSWIRE) -- Specialty diagnostics company Precipio, Inc. (NASDAQ:PRPO), announced today it has settled its lawsuit with Crede Capital Group LLC, restructuring the final substantial liability of legacy payables **inherited as part of the merger** with Transgenomic in June 2017. (emphasis mine.)
>   (src: [GlobeNewswire](https://globenewswire.com/news-release/2018/03/13/1421335/0/en/Precipio-Settles-Lawsuit-with-Crede-Capital.html) <  Precipio, Inc.)

Devonshire-Ellis (Ed.) "Mergers & Acquisitions in China," [p.30](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=UqIW2lPL73QC&pg=PA30&dq=%22inherited%20liabilities%22%20Chris%20Devonshire-Ellis&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj6tNW5k8ncAhXMQY8KHfAIDX8Q6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=%22inherited%20liabilities%22%20Chris%20Devonshire-Ellis&f=false) (GoogleBooks)

> An equity transaction is subject to full approval of the Chinese authorities and thus is time-consuming and may also expose you to existing liabilities. An investor will assume all of the existing obligations, liabilities and restrictions of the target company so careful due diligence must be carried out. Despite the greater risks from **inherited liabilities**, equity acquisitions tend to still be more popular in China compared to asset acquisitions, … …. (emphasis mine.)

Comment: Thank you sir, we are after a single word that apparently may exist...

Comment: @Shabbash18 there's no guarantee of a single word and even if one existed, a multi word term may actually be more idiomatic.

Comment: @Shabbash18 *Inherited* is a single word. (Look at its use in the first quote provided.) You haven't given us an example sentence in which a single word could be placed that would prevent its use.